# Flutter Dynamic Links Not Functioning Correctly on iOS (Works on Android)

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I've developed a Flutter app with a feature that leverages dynamic links for league joining purposes. The app is working as intended on Android and has been successfully launched on Google Play. However, I am encountering issues with the iOS version.

## Expected Behavior (Android):

When a participant user clicks on the dynamic link, they are redirected to a league joining screen.

If the user has already joined the league, a message is displayed indicating the league is already joined.

If an admin user clicks the link, they are redirected to the home page.

## Current iOS Behavior:

When a participant user clicks on the link, it merely opens the app without redirecting to the league joining screen or showing any message.

If the app is not installed on an iOS device, clicking the link opens Safari with a prompt to open in the app. However, clicking this button just reloads the Safari page with an error message stating "Safari can't open the page."

Are there any known issues with Flutter's handling of dynamic links on iOS that differ from Android?

Could this be related to an iOS-specific setting or a configuration issue within my Flutter project?

Has anyone experienced similar issues and found a solution?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm particularly interested in understanding why the behavior differs between the two platforms and how to resolve it for iOS.

- Flutter version: 3.16.0
- Firebase Dynamic Links version: ^5.4.6
- iOS version tested on: 17.0